# Solve equation for z: $z^2=3+4i ,(z=x+iy)$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z^2=3+4i ,(z=x+iy)$$
Seems easy? That's what I thought!

I get a system of equations that I can't solve:
$x^2-y^2=3$ and $2xiy=4i$ which I then get $x=\frac{2}{y}$

I can't solve the system of equations?

Comment: Plug the expression of $x$ in the first equation. Set $X=1/x^2$, you get a quadratic equation in $X$...

Comment: One can easily guess $x=2$ and $y=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$3+4i = 4+4i-1$$ $$ = 4+4i+i^2 $$

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! Didn't really look at it this way

Answer (score 2):

Taking norms, you have: $|z|^2 = |3 + 4i|$, so $x^2 + y^2 = 5$. Combining this with $x^2 - y^2 = 3$ yields $2x^2 = 8$, hence $x = \pm 2$.

Comment: Also helpful. Thank you!